# Connect to URL Sqlite Database C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

Is there a way that I can connect to a database called shop.sqlite that is located on: **https://server/network/share/shop.sqlite** (ideally)
or on: **\\servername\sharedfolder\shop.sqlite**

currently I open the database in the folder of the application, but for this particular application I would like to write to a database located on the network. Is this possible?

```
rc = sqlite3_open("shop.db", &db);
```

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended. SQLite is not optimized for network access. Too many ins/outs will happen. 

Recommended to use another rdbms like MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For a HTTP/HTTPS URL: No. HTTP is read-only. HTTP *can* be used to write (how else am I uploading this answer?), but it's application-specific - there isn't a standard widely-supported protocol for this, so SQLite wouldn't know about it.

For a Windows shared files: *Yes*. Just use `\\servername\sharedfolder\shop.sqlite` as the path. If you write it in the C++ program, make sure to escape the backslashes: `"\\\\servername\\sharedfolder\\shop.sqlite"`. Windows lets you read and write shared files just as easily if they were on your own hard disk.

If SQLite doesn't like the "UNC" path format (`\\servername\`) for some reason, you can map `\\servername\sharedfolder` to a drive letter (say `Z:`), and use the drive letter (`Z:\shop.sqlite`). Then it *really* looks like a normal disk.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
rc = sqlite3_open("\\\\my-computer\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\application\\Database\\shop.sqlite",&db);
```

Which worked!

I know it's not recommended but it did exactly what I required so I am very grateful.